# Can You Use Element ID to Check if the Element is Clickable

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

Does this line of code work for testing if an element can be clicked.

`WebDriverWait(driver, .5).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, ButtonElm)))`
if not what would be the correct way to check if an element is clickable, by using its Element ID

Answer (score 0):

```
# Set higher wait time
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,10)
try:
    element = wait.until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, ButtonElm)))   
# Or check Selenium exceptions for clickable, but you could receive either
# not found or not clickable errors here.
except Exception as e:
    do stuff
    pass
```

Comment: Just to be clear ButtonElm = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button"), does the element_to_be_clickable still work?

Comment: i think you should check element visibility( visibility_of_element_located )first and then use element to be clickable.

Comment: edit the answer if you like that way we can handle both possible exceptions. element not being there plus element not being clickable.